# Impossible to connect to minecraft remote server : connection refused

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, minecraft

I'm trying to set a Minecraft 1.15.1 server on my Ionos Cloud Ubuntu 18.04 server, used 3 differents tutorials, openned port 25565, allowed all users to access the folders.

The server runs perfectly, but when I tried to connect to it I get the error :
`io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information`

No informations on the minecraft logs, can't find anything on apache logs.

I there a log anywhere which can provide me informations about the problem blocking the connections to the minecraft server ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Apache? Is there a firewall? Can you use netcat on each end with that port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved : Ionos, my server provider, have an extra firewall which is controlled in my server control panel. I added the port to the whitelist and now it's working perfectly.